# CSS styles get applied without class declaration

Tags: html, css, sass

Now, this is a new one ... I have a class declaration in SCSS:

```
.video {
  a {
    // some stuff
  }
}
```

There are the classes: wrap - container - row - content and then some html:

```
<div class="btn-large">
  <a href="#" class="btn btn-default">View more</a>
</div>
```

This 'a' has the styles from '.video a' applied, but in the whole source, there's no mention of 'video'. I checked the compiled css and it's '.video a'. The rule also shows up as applied in Safari (and Chrome, and Firefox). How's that possible?

Comment: can you please add jsfiddle

Comment: And you're absolutely, positively sure that the "some stuff" appears only there in the stylesheet?

Comment: I'm absolutely certain, yes. And it says in the inspector for applied rules '.video a'.

Comment: If possible provide the link of your webpage which has this issue to get a proper solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way for the styles to be applied if the selector doesn't match.

You have ruled out the class appearing in the source.

Therefore, it is being added to some element using JavaScript.

Comment: Is there any way to figure out if the DOM is manipulated and from which function?

Comment: Identify the element that is modified through the DOM inspector, then set a Break on Attribute Change.

Comment: Thanks, that helped. 'video' was applied together with 'audio' and other classes to <html>.